# What does `when` return when the condition is false?

Tags: scheme, conditional-statements, evaluation, guile

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (define val (when #f 1))
scheme@(guile-user)> val
scheme@(guile-user)> (null? val)
$6 = #f
scheme@(guile-user)> (boolean? val)
$7 = #f
scheme@(guile-user)> (pair? val)
$8 = #f
scheme@(guile-user)> (when val 1)
$9 = 1
```

It does evaluate to `#t` but what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update: the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html#index-when) says: *"When ... the test evaluates to `#f`, the value of the expression is not specified."* So it might be anything, and shouldn't be relied upon for anything.

---

It returns a value which is not `null?`, not `boolean?` and not `pair?`:

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (null? val)
$6 = #f
scheme@(guile-user)> (boolean? val)
$7 = #f
scheme@(guile-user)> (pair? val)
$8 = #f
```

It is not an `#f`, as evidenced by

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (when val 1)
$9 = 1
```

And it *prints* as nothing,

```
scheme@(guile-user)> val
scheme@(guile-user)>
```

So what is it? *A value is defined by its interactions.* Its internal representation in a specific implementation is not that important.

Short answer is, it is a "not a value". (sic)

Chez Scheme [prints it as `#<void>`](https://tio.run/##K07OSM1N1QWSVf//a6SkpmXmpSqUJeYoaJRnpOYpKKcpGGpqcnFppGQWF@QkVoKkNP//BwA):

```
(define val (when #f 1))
(display val)
; Output:
#<void>
```

And Guile 2.0.13 at ideone.com [prints it as `#<unspecified>`](https://ideone.com/EPhbXV).

Comment: So, if it is not a value, why in [Guile Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Definition.html#Definition) it is said “To define a new variable, you use Scheme’s define syntax like this: `(define variable-name value)`
This makes a new variable called `variable-name` and stores `value` in it as the variable’s initial value.”  ?

Comment: @Renzo obviously I was being poetic more than I was being rigorous. :) maybe it's "not a value to be used anywhere". a special kind of value that is not a value in the same sense as a null pointer is not really a pointer. I dunno. :)

Comment: Ok, I was just curious!

Comment: but actually, it doesn't change anything. `(when #f 1)` must return something; but it shouldn't return anything of value. what's the poor thing to do? return a special something which really is nothing. hence the "a" in "*a* 'not a value'".

Comment: I find Chez Schema more coherent with a vision of values returned by expressions (and this is an almost universal case): what an expression returns is something which is called a value, be it #<void> or #null or NIL or () or whatever, which has some role in the data system of the language. Otherwise the variable `val` is associated to something, which is not a value (but if a variable is initialized it is initialized to a value...)

Comment: I bet there's something specific in the Report about this, but I'm also pretty sure it won't change this explanation in a very significant way. What my answer is actually saying is, "this is self-evident, and it also makes sense".

Comment: btw Guile is returning some value too; it just might be that the OP's  specific version's way of  *printing* such values is to print nothing. ideone.com prints `#<unspecified>`. (I've edited that in, thanks).

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct that this is a special value simply not printed by default. For instance [Chez Scheme](https://www.scheme.com/csug8/objects.html) uses the term “Void object”, while [Racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/void.html?q=void) uses explicitly “#void value", or "constant #void" (and prints always it). Now it remains only to find the name of its type... :)

Comment: Does guile have documentation that "It returns a value which is not null?, not boolean? and not pair?"? The scheme reports, by design, underspecifies it so anything goes. Guile documentation for `define` doesn't specify what it returns, only the side effect it provides. It might do `#t` every odd line number and `#<unspecified>` the other times. One should not rely on underspecified behaviour.

Comment: @Sylwester you're right, of course. I was being too light-minded with this. the bottom line is the same though: it doesn't matter what it is, as it shouldn't ever be used for anything. but I wasn't clear enough about this.